# MongoDB: Get newest documents with distinct combination of two values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

So I have a question how to form a specific slightly more complicated query to the db.
I have a collection with documents something like:

```
[{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "Object1" },
  "created": { "$date" : "2021-11-14T10:58:01.456Z" },
  "primaryId": "SomeId1",
  "secondaryIdx": 0,
  "otherData" : something
}
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "Object2" },
  "created": { "$date" : "2021-11-13T10:58:01.456Z" },
  "primaryId": "SomeId2",
  "secondaryIdx": 0,
  "otherData" : something
}
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "Object3" },
  "created": { "$date" : "2021-11-15T10:58:01.456Z" },
  "primaryId": "SomeId2",
  "secondaryIdx": 1,
  "otherData" : something
}
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "Object4" },
  "created": { "$date" : "2021-11-16T10:58:01.456Z" },
  "primaryId": "SomeId1",
  "secondaryIdx": 0,
  "otherData" : something
}]
```

And my resulting collection should have only documents with unique combinations of primaryId + secondaryIdx. Wherever there is more then one document with this combination, I want to get only the newest one.
So my result should look like this:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "Object2" },
  "created": { "$date" : "2021-11-13T10:58:01.456Z" },
  "primaryId": "SomeId2",
  "secondaryIdx": 0,
  "otherData" : something
}
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "Object3" },
  "created": { "$date" : "2021-11-15T10:58:01.456Z" },
  "primaryId": "SomeId2",
  "secondaryIdx": 1,
  "otherData" : something
}
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "Object4" },
  "created": { "$date" : "2021-11-16T10:58:01.456Z" },
  "primaryId": "SomeId1",
  "secondaryIdx": 0,
  "otherData" : something
}]
```

So the Object1 gets excluded from the result because the primaryId+secondaryIdx is duplicate and Object4 is newer.

I currently have this implemented in my application but I think it would be better the do this at a query level, so my application doesn't have to load unneccesarily big collections and then have to potentially filter out a large portion of them immediately anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first `$sort` by `primaryId: 1, secondaryIdx: 1, created: -1`. Then do a `$group` by the `primaryId + secondaryIdx` then take the first document.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      primaryId: 1,
      secondaryIdx: 1,
      created: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        primaryId: "$primaryId",
        secondaryIdx: "$secondaryIdx"
      },
      lastDoc: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$lastDoc"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/z3k12k63Zj_) for your reference.

Comment: Is there any reasons why you sort by primaryId & secondaryIdx? Just with the creation date is enough to get the expected output.

Comment: Actually the sorting is not compulsory, but in my past experience, usually your use case will be aided by a compound index like `primaryId: 1, secondaryIdx: 1, created: -1`, since you are doing a grouping operation. If you are also benefited from existence of such an index, you might want to leverage the index too.

Comment: So if there is a compound index with `primaryId: 1, secondaryIdx: 1, created: -1`, and not a single one with only `created: -1`, is it more efficient to sort by all fields (even if it is not necessary) to use the index?

Comment: Yes, you are right. You can refer to [this official MongoDB document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-intersection/#std-label-index-intersection-compound-indexes) for more information.

Comment: Thank you this seems to be exactly what I need.